# Elements are not sticking in their position when screen is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a page and a form element that I have positioned on the right side of the page, when I resize the page the form moves to the left of the page, this is very irritating and I want to keep the element fixed.

The element is `<div id = "form1">` in the below code:

```
<center>
<div id = "text">

<p>Angus Animal Sanctuary is a small animal centre located in Birmingham, UK.  Our focus is on more traditional pets like cat, dogs, rabbits and birds. The objectives of this association are to take in and re-home animals and provide a special living environment. </p>
<p>An animal adoption makes a unique gift idea for yourself or someone special and provides a valuable contribution to the running costs of Angus. With the help of our staff and volunteers we provide a special and loving atmosphere to help all our animals adapt and find permanent, loving new homes.</p> 
<p>All potential adopters are interviewed and home vetted.</p> 
</div>

<div id = "form1">

<form method="login" action="form1.php">
<center><h3>Login</h3></center>
       <label>Email*:</label> <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" placeholder="abc@mail.co.uk" required value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>"/>
       <br/><div class="error"><?php if (!empty($emailErr)){echo $emailErr;}?></div>
       <br/>
       <label>Password*:</label> <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="20" placeholder="**********" required value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password);?>"/>
       <br/><div class="error"><?php if (!empty($passwordErr)){echo $passwordErr;}?></div>
       <br/>
       <b><input style="float:right" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Sign In"/></b>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
width:979px;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}


 body{
min-width:947px;
}


/* change padding to increase or decrease size */
#header{
background-color:#C8C800;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height:150px; 
    width:950px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999; 

}
#form1{

   margin-top:-250px;
   background-color:#FBFBE8;
   margin-right:190px;
   float:right;
   padding:0;
   width:240px;
   height:180px;
   border:1px solid #999;
   border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    display:inline;
}

/* Main setting of the nav bar */
#nav{
background-color:#C8C800;
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999; 
    width:950px;
text-align: left;
border:0px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Styling to change anything which goes on the navbar itself */
#nav ul {list-style:none; 
            text-align: center;
            margin: 4px;        /* This changes height of navbar (orange bar)*/
            font-family: BOOK ANTIQUA; 
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic; 

}

#nav li {
    display: inline; 
}

/* Styling to change the specific button / link of navbar  (li) because it is reffering to lists*/
#nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    padding: 20px 20px;  /* This changes width and height of the buttons, edit 2nd one to increase/decrease spacing between links*/
    background-color:#C8C800; 
}


/* Styling to change the specific button / link of navbar */
#nav li a:hover { 
        color: #FFF; 
        background-color: black;
}


 #text{
  line-height:0.65cm;
  width:680px;
  margin-right:270px;
  margin-top:-40px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:#FBFBE8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
  webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;

  }

  #footer{
  background-color:#C8C800;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
  webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px #999;
  width: 945px;
}
```

Comment: @NicoO Not quite because when tested in a browser, the form starts of on the right hand side of the page after the white box

Comment: Yes i did just tested it my self. But your source is really messy... Let met see if i can help you. Will take a while.

Comment: @NicoO Yes the css is really messy I understand.. thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly i do not do this. But since I like animals, I gave your markup a little retuch. It's not complete but i think it will help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/Yqbg5/1/

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrap
{
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
}

#header
{
    background-color: #C8C800;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999999;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation
{
    display: block;
    margin:20px 0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C8C800;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999999;
}

#navigation > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#navigation > li A
{ 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: italic;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;

}


#navigation > li A:hover,
#navigation > li A:focus
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

#slideshow
{
    border:1px solid black;
    clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box
{
    background-color: #FBFBE8;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999999;
    padding: 15px;
}

.claimer
{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#left
{
    width:71.5%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#right
{
    margin-left: 71.5%;
}

#content:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; 
}



#footer 
{
    background-color: #C8C800;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #999999;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h3
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You will ned to change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <span class="claimer">Angus Animal Sanctuary</span>
    </div>

    <ul id="navigation"> 
        <li><a href="?">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="?">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="?">Contact us</a></li>    
    </ul>

    <div id="slideshow">
        <img name="slide"  src="http://www.katellaclinic.com/clients/6909/images/bigstock_Group_Of_Pets_Together_In_Fron_8258872.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
        <div class="box">
        <h3>Welcome to Angus Animal Sanctuary</h3>
        <p>Angus Animal Sanctuary is a small animal centre located in Birmingham, UK.  Our focus is on more traditional pets like cat, dogs, rabbits and birds. The objectives of this association are to take in and re-home animals and provide a special living environment. </p>
        <p>An animal adoption makes a unique gift idea for yourself or someone special and provides a valuable contribution to the running costs of Angus. With the help of our staff and volunteers we provide a special and loving atmosphere to help all our animals adapt and find permanent, loving new homes.</p> 
        <p>All potential adopters are interviewed and home vetted.</p> 
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <div class="box">
        <form action="form1.php" method="login">
            <h3>Login</h3> 
            <label for="name">Email*:</label> 
            <input type="text" value="" required="" placeholder="abc@mail.co.uk" maxlength="20" size="15" id="name" name="name" />

            <label for="password">Password*:</label> 
            <input type="password" value="" required="" placeholder="" maxlength="20" size="15" id="password" name="password" />
            <input type="Submit" value="Sign In" name="Submit" /> 
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <marquee><b>All Content Copyright 2014</b></marquee>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Ryman Holmes, i saw your edit that was declined by the Community. I removed the personal information and i will change the jsfiddle also

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS

```
#form1{
    position:relative;
    left:195px;}
```

It should help.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the form with a div, then add the css `posion: relative` to this div.